# Why is there vertical scroll on the main container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am very much confused here. Since the `body` is 100% (width/height) and `main-container` is also 100% (width/height), why is there vertical scroll?

I created a jsFiddle to explain the situation: http://jsfiddle.net/dcnnvgs1/1/

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS !important";
  background-color: #00b3b3;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-header {
  background-color: #099;
  height: 10%;
}

.main-footer {
  background-color: #099;
  height: 10%;
}

.main-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="main-header">HEADER</div>
    <div class="main-content">jecechejbhcbjbcjrbjb bbjbhbbk</div>
    <div class="main-footer">FOOTER</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `body` tag by default has a margin depend on the browser as example in chrome its `margin:8px`you have to rest it via

```
body{
  margin:0;
}
```

see updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcnnvgs1/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You have to reset default body margin.

```
body,html{
width:100%;
height:100%;
font-family:"Trebuchet MS !important";
 background-color:#00b3b3;
  margin:0px; //reset default body margin
}
```

Every tag have it default css property which is depends upon browser.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your code:

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

---

All browsers have a ***default style sheet***. It provides a basic set of styles.

Here is a sample default style sheet from the W3C: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/sample.html

As you can see from the sample, `body { margin: 8px; }` is a recommended default setting.

When you add that margin space to your `height: 100%` it causes an overflow.

So add `body { margin: 0; }` to override the default.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to set body width to 100%. It will automatically take the full width.

```
body,html{
 /*width:100%;*/
 height:100%;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS !important";
 background-color:#00b3b3;
}
```

Comment: Although this is true it is not an answer to the question. Consider posting as a comment.